# Dedicate 5.2 GHz to video streaming

Tags: windows-7, media, video-streaming

I have a cisco e4200 router capable of running 5.2 and 2.4 GHz simultaneously. On a windows 7 machine, I have a cisco wusn600n wireless adapter. From the windows 7 machine, I stream full hd videos to a couple of western Digital media live maedia players elsewhere in the house. These players are connected to the wifi system by a couple of other wusb600n adapters.

The system works well and I can usually stream 2 full HD videos at the same time. However, issues sometimes occur if someone is also using the Internet as the WUSB600n adapters can only work at either 5.2 or 2.4 GHz. I have a couple of spare dlink dwa 140 adapters that can stream video at 300mhz but only at 2.4 GHz. I want to connect these to the Windows 7 machine and bind all applications except the Windows mediaplayer service to them to stop other applications from using the 5.2 GHz band. Anyone know if or how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your router supports WMM (Wireless Multimedia). WMM is used to allow specific kinds of wireless traffic (like video) to be set to high priority—working very much like QoS but requiring less configuration.
This should help.

Comment: Every router that supports 802.11n supports WMM. It's part of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

This will be hard to do and likely counter-productive anyway. But what will help is to put all your media sending devices on one band and your receiving devices on the other. This way, the receiving and sending won't have to wait for each other and halve the bandwidth. The AP has to receive the media data from the sending device and then send the media data to the receiving device. You don't want those two expensive operations sharing a radio if they don't have to.